# Custom Fonts in Application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, fonts

I have one font named ArnovalTCStd.otf which I want to use in my iPad application for some labels. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There hasn’t been an easy way to add custom fonts to your iPhone applications. As of iOS 4 it has become very easy to do. Here is what you need to do in order to add custom fonts:

Check  [How to include ttf fonts to iOS app](http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html)

Comment: @Jhaliya hi .. Thanks for the ans. but i m used "CharlemagneStd-Bold.otf.otf" font . and its not working for me. i have set the property as your reference link . give me some suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that your font is supported for iPad.
Please use following loop to identify list of Font Family

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"Font Family = %@", familyName);

    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]){
        NSLog(@"\t%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your  fonts in application's resources folder.

in info.plist file 
add new row  with name
**Fonts  provided by application** it will be of type array
add  item in it.
write  your font name in item's value
example:-Birch.TTF

than in your code write following line:-

```
[label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Birch" size:36.0]];
```