# Can't add custom font to application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am having trouble using a custom font in my application.

The following describes the steps I took

1 - Add **.TTF** font to application
2 - Modify the **info.plist** file.
3 - Add the key **"Fonts provided by application"** to a new row
4 - And add each **.TTF** file *(of font)* to each line.

So I have an array of fonts, each of which has a **.ttf** extension.

And then I try to add the font

```
UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 65, 230, 33)];
lblName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[lblName  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"acmesab" size:32]]; // acmesab is my custom "font" name.
lblName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lblName.text = @"Name:";
[simapleView addSubview:lblName];
```

Comment: open the ttf file in "font book" (Mac Application) and check what's the actual name of the font. Don't use the font name as of the filename of TTF file. Use the font name shown in "Font Book"

Comment: Check that your fonts are added in "Copy bundle Resources"

Comment: @samfisher- if this font is not available in my 'Font Book' then what i need to do ??

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your font-properties what the actual font-name is. 
Sometimes you import the font with name `FjallaOne-Regular`. But if you look at the properties you see that the font is named like `Fjalla One`.

Therefore you need to use it like this.

```
[lblName  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Fjalla One" size:32]];
```

Instead of

```
[lblName  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FjallaOne-Regular" size:32]];
```

Also check if you set the correct `target membership`

You can see what I mean by the correct name over here

[LINK](http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/EiBLk6.png)

Comment: @stef.. how can i see what is actual name of my font even this type of font is not available in my "Font Book".. and also i dont wnat to install this font to my "FONT BOOK" also.. so please give me suggestion ..

Comment: @Ranju if font which you want to use is not available in your "Font Book" then you have to install it and when you open it you can show the name of font,paste that name.

Comment: Why you don't want to install it in your fontbook. I think their is the only way you can see it

Answer (score 0):

For the custom font first you have to install your .ttf file in your system.after that import it to your project. Rename .ttf file as shown in "FontBook"  and
add

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
    <string>Times New Roman.ttf</string>
</array>
```

in your info.plist file. and then use it as fontname in your project

```
CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Name" fontName:@"Times New Roman" fontSize:26];
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your project -> Targeta -> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources. Check your files are shows in list or not? If not then add them and run the application again.It should work.

Use following code to check whether font is added or not and add appropriate font name from listing.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
    [fontNames release];
}
[familyNames release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky sometimes as certain fonts don't seem to be recognised. Have a look at my answer from a few months ago which might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170599/331854